# Como contar quantos campos estão vazios na tabela do mysql

Tags: mysql, select, count

Tenho uma tabela de cadastro de terrenos com varias colunas (algumas delas: id, endereco, cidade, proposta, etc) e gostaria de fazer uma contagem de quantos campos estão vazios.

Por exemplo, a tabela tem no total 44 colunas, se só tiverem 20 campos preenchidos, a consulta sql deverá trazer o resultado 24, que são em branco ou null.

É possível fazer isso?

Ele tem que fazer a busca de terrenos e deve apresentar a tabela assim para que a pessoa saiba quantos campos ela não preencheu e está faltando:

```
ID terreno|camposembranco
1         | 5
2         | 2
3         | 0
```

Comment: Não entendi se você quer verificar isso por linha ou na tabela como um todo.

Comment: na tabela como um todo, são cadastros de terrenos, aí preciso saber quantos campos ainda não foram preenchidos, por exemplo, não preencheu só a cidade, aí vou mostrar que falta 1 campo para ser preenchido, vou editar a pergunta para ficar melhor

Comment: Então é por linha. Quer dizer, você quer saber que falta a cidade para o terreno X. Ou saber se a cidade está em branco para TODOS os terrenos?

Comment: desculpa, isso, por linha, tipo linha do ID 2 faltam 5 campos, linha do ID 7 Faltam 8

Answer (score 1):

Existem outras formas de fazer, porém, eu utilizo da seguinte maneira:

```
    SELECT 
      ((CASE WHEN COLUNA1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      + (CASE WHEN COLUNA2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     .
     .
     .
     .
      + (CASE WHEN COLUNA5 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'SOMA DE NULOS'
    FROM SUA_TABELA
```

Essa instrução atribui 0 ou 1 dependendo se a coluna é nula ou não. E ai realizando a soma em um único campo (SOMA DE NULOS).

Basta alterar as colunas e o nome da tabela para o seu modelo.

Segue um modelo de exemplo..

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/23a13/1/0)

Comment: então eu tenho que fazer uma consulta para cada coluna ne? não existem uma forma de fazer de 1 só vez

Comment: Pode colocar tudo na mesma consulta Leandro. Aonde está 'COLUNA1', 'COLUNA2' , seriam suas próprias colunas. Você só vai precisar fazer mais de uma vez se for por tabela. No exemplo que coloquei existem 3 colunas que estou buscando usando o mesmo Select, da uma olhada la